# Cordova or phonegap : saving file catcher

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I curently develop an app in javascript and I want to use cordova or phonegap to adapt my code to android, Iphone, etc. But in my app I save my file with this function :

```
function save(){
    var myFileJSON = JSON.stringify(myFile);
    try{
        var blob = new Blob([myFileJSON], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
        saveAs(blob, "myFileJSON.txt");
    } catch (e){
        console.log('bug');
    }
}
```

So with my phone application I want to save my file in a specific folder. Can I catch the save event and, for exemple, redirect immediately the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function saveCourseToFile() {
   console.log("checkpoint 1");
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, onFSError);
}
function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
   console.log("checkpoint 2");
   console.log("Opened file system: " + fileSystem.name);
   fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create:true, exclusive:false}, gotFileEntry, onFSError);
}
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
   console.log("checkpoint 3");
   fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, onFSError);
}
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
   writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
      console.log("checkpoint 4: write success!");
   };
   writer.write("test test test");
}
```

You can also check [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) link for your reference.

Comment: So when I call save with my js this fonction in phone app will save it where I want?

Comment: Saved file will be available in the root folder. And please accept the answer if it is useful.